# Data Augmentation for Object Detection - Polygon Region Shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, object-detection, data-annotations

I'm looking to run a Mask RCNN code on my dataset of about 2700 images. The images are too large and I would like to resize them, and I would also like to add some shear, scale and zoom augmentations.

Since this is an object detection task, it requires augmentation of annotated images with bounding boxes. Most of the resources I found dealt with rectangular bounding boxes which seems relatively straightforward.

However, my images have polygon bounding boxes. Here's an example:
[image]

I'm currently using the VGG annotator and the bounding box values are stores in a JSON file. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library such as IMGAUG (https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/installation.html)

Here is a link to a notebook where you can practice using the augmentations along with the polygons.

https://nbviewer.org/github/aleju/imgaug-doc/blob/master/notebooks/B03%20-%20Augment%20Polygons.ipynb

Once you are happy that you know how you want to augment your images you can use it with MaskRCNN in the following manner.

```
import imgaug.augmenters as iaa

augmentation = iaa.Sequential([
            iaa.Fliplr(0.5), # horizontal flips
            # Small gaussian blur with random sigma between 0 and 0.5.
            # But we only blur about 50% of all images.
            iaa.Sometimes(0.5,
                iaa.GaussianBlur(sigma=(0, 0.5))
            ),
            # Strengthen or weaken the contrast in each image.
            iaa.ContrastNormalization((0.75, 1.5)),
            # Apply affine transformations to each image.
            # Scale/zoom them, translate/move them, rotate them and shear them.
            iaa.Affine(
                scale={"x": (0.8, 1.2), "y": (0.8, 1.2)},
                translate_percent={"x": (-0.2, 0.2), "y": (-0.2, 0.2)},
                rotate=(-10, 10),
                shear=(-2, 2))
            ], random_order=True) # apply augmenters in random order

model.train(dataset_train, dataset_val,
                    learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE,
                    epochs=20,
                    layers='heads',
                    augmentation=augmentation)
```